# Relativistic Effects with Gravitational Fields

Tags: special-relativity

I recently learned how magnetic forces on point charges can be viewed as purely electric forces on point charges in the appropriate reference frame. This got me thinking if there was a similar effect with gravity. Consider an infinite, massive plane of mass density $\sigma$. If we have some point mass, $m$, located in space, the gravitational force on the mass is $2\pi m \sigma G$ towards the plane. However, let's say this plane were to be moving at a relativistic speed $v$ parallel to itself. Then, the new mass density of the plane would be $\sigma _{\text{new}} = \gamma \sigma$ where $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$, so the gravitational force on the point mass would be multiplied by $\gamma$. Is this what happens, or am I missing something? If the plane were to start moving at high speeds (or the particle -- it doesn't really matter due to the first postulate of relativity), would the gravitational force increase?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Related [Gravitoelectromagnetism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism)

Comment: *magnetic forces on point charges can be viewed as purely electric forces on point charges in the appropriate reference frame* You cannot Lorentz-transform a pure magnetic field into a pure electric field (because $E^2-B^2$ is a Lorentz invariant). Magnetic forces are not there “because I’m using the wrong frame”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would the gravitational force increase?

Yes. Because of three reasons:

1. Length contraction
2. Increase of energy
3. Motion in curved space